# Function in C that realize the mathematical union of two arrays of int in another one

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

The language is ANSI C. I have 2 arrays of `int`: `A` and `B`. `A` has an index called `m` and `B` an index called `n`. The assignment says that `m` MUST BE different from `n`, so the arrays must have different size. I have coded already this. `A` is ordered ascending while `B` is ordered descending. I have to write a function that does the mathematical union of the two arrays in another one called `C`. If an element is in both the arrays you have to put only one in the array of the union (array `C`).

My code does not work very well. The last element is not ordered, I receive an output with a very big last number that I do not know from where it comes.

```
int index_c=index_m+index_n; //the index of array c
// is obtained by the sum of two indexes of the array A and B
int c[index_c];
int k=0;
for (i=0; i < index_m; i++)
{   
    for (j=0; j < index_n; j++)
    {    
        if (a[i]==b[j])
        {
            c[k]=a[i]; //put only one time if is repeated more time in the two arrays
        }
        else 
        {
            c[k]=a[i]; //put the a[i] element in the array c
            c[k+1]=b[j]; //the element of the other array next to
        }

    }
    k++;
}

printf("Elements in array C are: \n");
for (i=0; i<index_c; i++)
    printf("element %d\n", c[i]);
```

It doesn't matter if the array C is not sorted, I will sort after the union. Any suggestions?

I am trying the suggestion of  put k++ when I add 1 input, and k+2 when I add two input to array C. Now It works a bit well, but it doesn't full work. I mean in output I have not big number values but one of the output value (the 3rd) is the same as the first.
Example: 3 9 3 2 5   The second 3 is wrong and it's missing a number that is covered by the second 3.
Other example 2 4 2 1 9

Comment: What is the expectation for 
 `A = 1 3 5 8 13`
and 
 `B = 5 4 2 0` ?

Comment: The best code should make a single pass over the two arrays.  You know that both arrays are ordered, albeit in opposite directions, so you should search one from the end to the start and the other from the start to the end in a simple merge process. It also gives you the output data in sorted order (you can choose between ascending and descending order if you wish). This gives you O(N) — linear — time instead of quadratic O(N*N) time which your skeletal code shows.   Always exploit ordering when it is available — it improves performance a lot.

Comment: @Jongware: the description says A is ordered ascending and B is ordered descending.  The code is not exploiting this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: true, but from the look of it, the code isn't exploiting *anything* :) (and yes, I must have missed that).

Comment: Only `c[0]` to `c[kindex_m]` given a value.  Rest of `c` is uninitialized.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I am coding since this morning. Sorry. The last element is not ordered, I mean the last element is not from anyone of the two arrays. Is a big number, I think it's a random number that comes because I try to access to an element that has an index bigger than the array. It's "after the last element". With that two arrays I need a C= 1 3 5 8 13 4 2 0 without repeated numbers in C. I have not problems with sorting, but I can not do the union.

Answer (score 2):

I spot two immediate logical errors which should be fixed at the very least:

1. you either store one number in `c`, when both inputs are the same, and increase `k` by 1, *or* you store *two* numbers into `c`. You should then increase `k` with 2 as well. In the code you have now, you only have to add another `+1` -- but consider putting these additions inside the `if..else` test blocks for clarity. Currently, you are overwriting the last one stored.
2. You print the result from 0 to `index_c`, the sum of the lengths of the two input arrays. That is not logical because you are throwing out numbers. Hence you get 'random' numbers as output; those are merely *uninitialized*, i.e. never written to. Print from 0 to `k`, as that *is* the valid range of your input.

Comment: I understood the second point so I have modified the printf, now the for goes from 0 to k. I think it's ok. I have not understood the first point; I am wrong because I store one number in c if the numbers in input are the same, and...? perhaps you mean I have to increase `k` by 1 after this? While when I store the two numbers I have to increase k two times? I try to put this your suggestion in if...else.

Comment: When you store 1 value, increase `k` by 1. So to store 2, increase it with `2`. Think of it as "storing one single value" ... *twice*.

Comment: `for (i=0; i < index_m; i++)
{   
    for (j=0; j < index_n; j++)
    {    
        if (a[i]==b[j])
        {
            c[k]=a[i]; //put only one time if is repeated more time in the two arrays
   k++
        }
        else 
        {
            c[k]=a[i]; //put the a[i] element in the array c
            c[k+1]=b[j]; //the element of the other array next to
           k=k+2;
        }

    }
    k++;
}

printf("Elements in array C are: \n");
for (i=0; i<k; i++)
    printf("element %d\n", c[i]);`
Is right?

Comment: No! You have `k+2` in the correct place but it will still execute `k++` right after it. Change to `k+1` *at the current position*, or, as I suggested, move the `k++` into the first part of your `if`.

Answer (score 2):

So far none of the answers exploit the fact that the arrays are both sorted. Here is an implementation which is almost identical to a *merge* as suggested in the comments. The complexity of the merge is O(m + n).

I have assumed that each array has no duplicates (no [0, 1, 1, 3]), but you could add checks like `if (k == 0 || k > 0 && C[k - 1] != A[i])` to fix this if I assumed wrong.

The function returns the length of `C`.`C` is sorted in increasing order. To have `C` be sorted in decreasing order instead change `if (A[i] < B[j])` to `if (A[i] > B[j])`.

```
int union_merge(const int *A, int m, const int *B, int n, int *C) {
  int i = 0, j = n - 1, k = 0;  

  while (i < m && j >= 0) {
    if (A[i] < B[j]) {
      C[k++] = A[i++];
    } else if (A[i] == B[j]) {
      C[k++] = A[i++];
      --j;
    } else {
      C[k++] = B[j--];
    }
  }

  while (j >= 0) {
    C[k++] = B[j--];
  }

  while (i < m) {
    C[k++] = A[i++];
  }

  return k;
}
```

Comment: Yay!  Thank you.  I was about to post an answer comparable to this.  Note that it is actually simpler just to write the two trailing `while` loops inline; only one of them (at most) will ever execute the body of the loop — neither will be executed if the last entry in `a` is equal to the first entry in `b`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that looks much cleaner now :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have two arrays A and B, and union array C. You can input both arrays A and B into one array. Then you can sort that array and after sorting iterate over array and add value to array C(union array) if you didn't already add that value.Total complexity is O( N * log(N) ) Look at code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100000

int a[2*MAX+3], c[2*MAX+3];

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  if ( *(int*)a <  *(int*)b ) return -1;
  if ( *(int*)a == *(int*)b ) return 0;
  if ( *(int*)a >  *(int*)b ) return 1;
}

int main() {

  int i, k;

  int n, m; scanf("%d%d", &n, &m); // size of the first array and size of the second array
  n += m;
  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) // O(N) , input both arrays into one array
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

  qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), cmp); // O( N * log(N) ), sort the given array

  c[0] = a[0];
  for(i = 1, k = 1; i < n; ++i) // O(N)
    if(c[k - 1] != a[i]) // if the last element that you added to the union array is different than the current element in first array then add that element to union array
      c[k++] = a[i];

  for(i = 0; i < k; ++i) // O(K)
    printf("%d ", c[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that your comparator function is subject to overflow if the value of the integers are large enough and of different signs.  That leads to undefined behaviour.  (For example, if one entry holds INT_MIN and another INT_MAX, the result of the subtraction is undefined.)  The chances are high that you're actually OK, but that isn't a good way to write a comparator function for the fully general case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for notification, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Oh dear: the revised comparator is just wrong.  The original used `return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b);` and was right for small enough integers (if the absolute value of every integer to be compared is less than `INT_MAX/2`).  The correct comparing comparator is probably: `int cmp(const void *pa, const void *pb) { int a = *(int *)a; int b = *(int *)b; if (a < b) return -1; else if (a > b) return +1; else return 0; }`.  Your current code (`return (*(int *a) > *(int *)b);` never returns a negative value as it should if the value pointed at by `a` is smaller than the value pointed at by `b`.

Comment: Also note that the comparators for C++ STL library code are different from the comparators for the C library `qsort()` and `bsearch()` functions.  The C++ comparators do return just a boolean value for (loosely) `*a > *b` (or maybe it is `*a < *b`); the comparator is used twice inside the comparing code to check for the ordering.